# how to pass class variables in vba function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to pass my set of objects and variables to VBA function, make some changes to it and pass it back as a result. So I create a sample Class1:

```
Public pInfo As String
```

and sample function:

```
Public Function populate(someVar As Class1) As Class1

    populate.pInfo = someVar.pInfo & " 1 "

End Function
```

and tryed to pass it to my function populate:

```
Sub test()
Dim v, w As Class1
Set v = New Class1
v.pInfo = "303"
Set w = populate(v) ' ERROR here

End Sub
```

results in compile error : byRef argument type mismatch.

UPDATE. Thanks to your help it compiles now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a type error

```
Dim v, w As Class1
```

Unintuitively here only `w` is of type `Class1`, `v` is a variant.
To make them both `Class1` you must:

```
Dim v As Class1, w As Class1
```

Here:

```
Public Function populate(someVar As Class1) As Class1
    populate.pInfo = someVar.pInfo & " 1 "
End Function
```

`populate` is not an instance of `Class1`, you need to create it:

```
Public Function populate(someVar As Class1) As Class1
    set populate = new Class1
    populate.pInfo = someVar.pInfo & " 1 "
End Function
```

(Rather than using a function you may prefer a `v.copyTo(w)`)

Comment: A method you create that does what your Populate does but inside the class

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  (I'm not the OP, just curious.)  I don't see any reference in the VBA object browswer to CopyTo.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to correct your `Populate()` method as follows:

```
Public Function Populate(someVar As Class1) As Class1      
    Dim z as Class1

    Set z = New Class1

    z.pInfo = someVar.pInfo & " 1 " 

    Set Populate = z

    Set z = Nothing
End Function
```

You also need to be aware that this will create a new instance of `Class1` so it will not inherit any of the other properties from `someVar`.